# Using Netwox 78 to disrupt telnet connection

Tags: ubuntu

i'm trying to use netwox in my local environment to disrupt a telnet from 2 machines using a third machine.

Machine 1's ip `10.0.2.5`

Machine 2's ip `10.0.2.6`

Machine 1 telnet's to machine 2

```
telnet 10.0.2.6
```

Once the telnet has been established, I would like to use machine 3 to and have the prompt say `Connection closed by foreign host.`.

On machine 3, I did `netwox 78 -i 10.0.2.6` and `netwox 78 -i 10.0.2.5` and nothing worked. May I ask what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A quick dig around finds `Netwox` that hit end-of-life in 2007, and a `Netwox 78` that has no `-i` flag. Do you [have a link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/352960/edit) to the flavour of `Netwox` that you are running, please.

Comment: You may be right there @roaima hmmm.

Comment: any thoughts on how to use it correctly. I can't find anything on netwox 78

Answer (score -1):

For telnet (port 23) you can try:

```
netwox 78 --device "Eth0" --filter "dst host 10.0.2.6 and dst port 23"
```